# Trigger event when angular 2 model value is complete binding in the view

Tags: angular

I need generate pdf from a angular 2  page automatically, when all the model value was load on the page. How can I know when all the model information was loaded into the view?

Comment: I think you're after `MutationObserver`

Comment: How do you load your model ? Can you give more details ? But as it said bellow take a look at subscribe method

Answer (score 0):

If your model is coming through an `@Input()` you can use the `OnChanges` module to track when the data is loaded. If you are loading the data through a promise, you can use a `.subscribe()` function to know when data is loaded, like this

`this.myModule.myFunction().subscribe(success => {createPDF()})`

But I don't know how to observe when the data is actually displayed in the html, but you could use a [debounceTime](https://medium.com/aviabird/rxjs-reducing-number-of-api-calls-to-your-server-using-debouncetime-d71c209a4613) or a [setTimeout](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/#_callbacks)